# Regex to capture comma separated numbers enclosed in quotes

Tags: node.js, regex

I have a large set of JavaScript snippets each containing a line like:

```
function('some string without numbers', '123,71')
```

and I'm hoping to get a regex together to pull the numbers from the second argument. The second argument can contain an arbitrary number of comma separated numbers (inlcuding zero numbers), so the following are all valid:

```
''
'2'
'17,888'
'55,1,6000'
...
```

The regex `'(?:\d+|,)*'` successfully matches the quoted numbers, but I have no idea how to match each of the numbers. Placing a capture group around the `\d+` seems to capture the last number (if there is one present -- it doesn't work if the second argument is just `''`), but none of the others.

Comment: It sounds as if  all you need is to match all digit chunks, i.e. `str.match(/\d+/g)`. Do you really need to check the context?

Comment: I am only passed the JavaScript snippet. While the rest of the snippet contains no quoted comma separated numbers, there possibly are other numbers included in the snippet.

Comment: Good,  I added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you may match and *capture* the digits inside the single quotes and then split them with a comma:

```js
var s = "function('some string without numbers', '123,71')";
var res = s.match(/'([\d,]+)'/) || ["", ""];
console.log(res[1].split(','));
```

The `/'([\d,]+)'/` regex will match a `'`, then 1+ digits or commas (placing that value into Group 1) and then a closing `'`.

If you want to run the regex globally, use

```js
var s = "function('some string without numbers', '123,71')\nfunction('some string without numbers', '13,4,0')";
var rx = /'([\d,]+)'/g;
var res = [], m;
while ((m=rx.exec(s)) !== null) {
  res.push(m[1].split(','));
}
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I was trying to do everything in 1 hit, and it didn't occur to me to split things up in two parts :)

Comment: You could do it "in one go" in PHP, .NET, Java, Swift, everywhere you can use `\G` or where capture stack is supported (.NET, Python `regex` module). JS regex does not support those features.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a numbers in a variable `x` like this:

```
var x = '55,1,6000';
```

then use this to have the list of numbers:

```
var array = x.split(',');
```

If you can have some whitespace before/after the comma then use:

```
var array = x.split('\s*,\s*');
```

or something like that.

Sometimes it is easier to match the thing that you don't want and split on that.